# @Entity table isn't getting generate in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

After running the project, shouldnt the user table be generated automatically in my database? I am refreshing it after running the server as well, but the user table isn't showing up in mysql.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BloggingApp
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace
```

User class

```
package com.example.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String about;
}
```

Main

```
package com.example.blogging.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EntityScan
public class BloggingAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BloggingAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Project structure:

[image]

Comment: Can You try to use org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect if You use MySQL8, or other version according with Your MySQL version. 
Can You show us logs? Also, can You add @EnableAutoConfiguration if it is missing in configurations?

Comment: Please add this property: spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true

Comment: And add packages to be scanned for entities: @EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.entities"). This is necessary because your main application class is in a different package.

Comment: thanks @Mar-Z those suggestions worked

Comment: @Mar-Z could you check this out too? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76265356/404-error-for-post-request-using-springboot

Comment: You have similar problem with base packages for JPA repositories. Add EnableJPARepositories annotation.

Comment: It would be easier just to change the package of main class to com.example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your entity package is different than spring boot main class, you will have to specify the package in `@EntityScan`

```
@EntityScan("com.example.entities.*")
```