# 404 error for post request using springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I am getting a 404 error for the following post request. This is the first API I am making using spring-boot. Is there something I am missing? What's going wrong?

This is how I am calling the request from postman:

[image]

Main file

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.example.entities.*" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class BloggingAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BloggingAppApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller file. It just has one function for adding a user.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    //POST: create user
    @PostMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> createUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto){
        UserDto createdUser = this.userService.createUser(userDto);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(createdUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    //GET: get user

    //PUT: update user

    //DELETE: delete user
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImp implements UserService {

    private UserRepo userRepo;
    @Override
    public UserDto createUser(UserDto userDto) {
        User user = this.dtoToUser(userDto);
        User savedUser = this.userRepo.save(user);

        return this.userToDto(savedUser);
    }
}
```

User Repo

```
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

Logs

```
9:58:05 pm: Executing ':BloggingAppApplication.main()'...

> Task :compileJava
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes

> Task :BloggingAppApplication.main()

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.6)

2023-05-16T21:58:07.212+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.blogging.app.BloggingAppApplication  : Starting BloggingAppApplication using Java 17.0.1 with PID 87851 (/Users/sahilsahu/Springboot-Projects/BloggingApp/build/classes/java/main started by sahilsahu in /Users/sahilsahu/Springboot-Projects/BloggingApp)
2023-05-16T21:58:07.217+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.blogging.app.BloggingAppApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-05-16T21:58:07.293+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-05-16T21:58:07.293+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-05-16T21:58:08.033+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-05-16T21:58:08.063+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 15 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-05-16T21:58:08.926+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-05-16T21:58:08.940+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-05-16T21:58:08.941+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
2023-05-16T21:58:09.021+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-05-16T21:58:09.024+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1728 ms
2023-05-16T21:58:09.233+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-05-16T21:58:09.290+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.7.Final
2023-05-16T21:58:09.623+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-05-16T21:58:10.008+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@8a123ef
2023-05-16T21:58:10.010+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-05-16T21:58:10.059+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
2023-05-16T21:58:10.084+05:30 DEBUG 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.d.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry          : addDescriptor(12, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.CapacityDependentDdlType@2c90ea34) replaced previous registration(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.CapacityDependentDdlType@39b5bd89)
2023-05-16T21:58:10.084+05:30 DEBUG 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.d.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry          : addDescriptor(-9, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.CapacityDependentDdlType@2f5c3b05) replaced previous registration(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.CapacityDependentDdlType@267cd5c2)
2023-05-16T21:58:10.085+05:30 DEBUG 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.d.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry          : addDescriptor(-3, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.CapacityDependentDdlType@d965a73) replaced previous registration(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.CapacityDependentDdlType@195bf7bd)
2023-05-16T21:58:10.085+05:30 DEBUG 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.d.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry          : addDescriptor(4003, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.DdlTypeImpl@57917380) replaced previous registration(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.DdlTypeImpl@17837e75)
2023-05-16T21:58:10.085+05:30 DEBUG 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.d.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry          : addDescriptor(4001, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.DdlTypeImpl@2879fb34) replaced previous registration(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.DdlTypeImpl@6ed91799)
2023-05-16T21:58:10.085+05:30 DEBUG 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.d.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry          : addDescriptor(4002, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.DdlTypeImpl@328874b1) replaced previous registration(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.DdlTypeImpl@3ef4c443)
2023-05-16T21:58:10.085+05:30 DEBUG 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.d.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry          : addDescriptor(2004, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.CapacityDependentDdlType@593328f2) replaced previous registration(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.DdlTypeImpl@7f708992)
2023-05-16T21:58:10.085+05:30 DEBUG 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.d.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry          : addDescriptor(2005, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.CapacityDependentDdlType@eac4731) replaced previous registration(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.DdlTypeImpl@16624c7b)
2023-05-16T21:58:10.086+05:30 DEBUG 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.d.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry          : addDescriptor(2011, org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.CapacityDependentDdlType@565682fd) replaced previous registration(org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.internal.DdlTypeImpl@2d11adbc)
2023-05-16T21:58:10.436+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-05-16T21:58:10.448+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-05-16T21:58:10.495+05:30  WARN 87851 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-05-16T21:58:10.945+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-05-16T21:58:10.981+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-05-16T21:58:10.993+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.blogging.app.BloggingAppApplication  : Started BloggingAppApplication in 4.207 seconds (process running for 4.709)
2023-05-16T21:58:16.081+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-16T21:58:16.081+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-16T21:58:16.083+05:30  INFO 87851 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

Comment: Just change the package of the main class to be a root of all other packages. Like com.example. This will help Spring to auto-configure.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove trailing slash from url in postman

> Currently, an endpoint registered in controller matches by default the defined path with trailing slash – for example, @GetMapping(“/some/greeting”) will match both /some/greeting and /some/greeting/ paths. In Spring Boot 3 this will no longer be supported by default due to security concerns. The previous behavior can be activated with appropriate configuration, although it is recommended to adjust the web application to use the new approach.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28552